# Modal Window not Showing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I've written the following piece of code using Bootstrap 3 but unfortunately the modal window is not showing. I don't know what is wrong with it. Please help. :)

```
<head>
    <!-- Loading Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container"> 
        <div class="row">
            <ul class="thumbnails">
                <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 thumb">
                    <a class="thumbnail" href="#bell" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#bell"><img src="img/thumbs/1.jpg"></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal Windows -->
    <div id="bell" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
                    <h3>Title</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p><img src="img/1.jpg" alt="" class="pull-right">Description</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Javascript -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no point including `bootstrap.js` in `<head>` and `jquery.js` in the bottom of the `<body>`. You better move `bootstrap.js` to the bottom and *after* jQuery.

Comment: You need to show the whole HTML (including the `<head>`) once again because it might contain the answer to your problem.

Comment: I've edited the code. Please have another look. :)

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: Yes. This: "Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery " while I've added the jquery at the bottom.

Comment: See my first comment then

Comment: I've posted almost whole of the html excluding the 'title' and 'meta-data' only.

Comment: Have you added jQuery **before** Bootstrap?

Comment: Yes. It's added before bootstrap.js

Answer (score 3):

You just need to remove the `hide` class from your modal container (`#bell`).

Since it's already having the `modal` class, Bootstrap knows to hide it until activated.

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e4s09uew/)

Comment: @Cartoon You're presumably looking at old Bootstrap v2 examples, since v2 did use `hide` but v3 doesn't. Stop reading outdated examples! v3 and v2 have major differences.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include jQuery before bootstrap.

The first line of bootstrap checks if jQuery is loaded and it is not wating on the DOM to be ready

```
if("undefined"==typeof jQuery)throw new Error("Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery");
```

Comment: I've made the edit but it's still not working. Though the console is n't showing any errors too.